# Realm: rearranging list of objects

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, realm

Please, tell me, how to rearrange items of Realm's list of objects by index? I.e. I'm looking something like

```
let movingElement = array[oldIndex]
array.removeAtIndex(oldIndex)
array.insert(movingElement, atIndex: newIndex)
```

if it was with a casual Swift array of something.

But for List in Realm I can not do the same thing:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var all = try! Realm().objects(element)
realm.write {
    all.removeAtIndex() // all of type
```

Another option is to

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let element = try! Realm().objects(Element)[oldIndex]
realm.write{
    realm.delete(element)
    realm.add(...)   // How to set index to place new object at?
}
```

But how to insert element in proper place? May be there is a proper method how to move elements of realm of the same type (class) by index?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it with query results, as they are unordered (or in a specific order if you sort them). But if you put them into Realm List (which you can store as member in a Realm object), then you can use both `move` and `swap` methods to reorder elements.

Here is the API docs for the the `List` type: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html